# Google translate - changing back to previous language doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

There seems to be a bug in Google translator which I am not able to get rid of. When we change the language, it works (web page gets translated to the desired language and the dropdown shows correct language), but when we try to switch to the previous language again, it does not work(it does not translate and shows 'select language' in the dropdown).

Same issue can be reproduced on any website having google translator.

eg: 
[w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp)
and 
[sitepointstatic.com](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/translate/index.html)

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Change the language to Catalan - Works
2. Change the language to English - Works
3. Change the language to Catalan - Doesn't work

Comment: any justification on downvote may help to improve the question

Comment: 6 years later and this is still an issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I remove the default language setting `pageLanguage: 'en'` option, this seems to fix the issue.

To include English as the first select option, I included it as the first option in `includedLanguages: 'en,am,bn,zh-CN'`.

I'm not sure how stable this solution is and couldn't find anything in the docs and couldn't find the google translate code to see what's going on.

Any links would be much appreciated.